# Segmentation Fault in g++ and reading from files

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, g++, fstream

I have a problem with this program, it reads from two files.
Each file, A and B contains an int at the top wich is the number of the strings it has. The program has to do a B - A operation, file A has 2 strings, "two" and "three". File B has 4 strings, "one", "two", "three" and "four". So the result in the third file has to be "one" and "four". Those which are not in the file A, but yes in file B.

First I read the size of each file, then the strings of each one.
 I calculate the size of result file and compare the strings of the two files.

I have used gdb debugger and it says that the problem is in the for that compares the files. What I do is:
If string in B, is not found in A, I put it in the result.

I write here the whole program (not too big) so you can get a better idea.

Many thanks and sorry for spanish name in variables.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main(){
int contador = 0;
string* datosA;
string* datosB;
string* resultado;
int tamA, tamB, tamResultado;

ifstream fichA("fA.txt");
if(fichA){
    fichA>> tamA;
    datosA = new string [tamA];

    for(int i = 0; i < tamA; i++){
        fichA>> datosA[i];
    }

    fichA.close();
}



ifstream fichB("fB.txt");

if(fichB){
    fichB>> tamB;

    datosB = new string [tamB];

    for(int i = 0; i < tamB; i++){
        fichB>> datosB[i];
    }

    fichB.close();
}



tamResultado = tamB - tamA;

resultado = new string [tamResultado];


contador = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < tamB; i++){
    bool enc = true;
    for(int j = 0; j < tamA && enc; j++){
        if(datosB[i] != datosA[j]){
            enc = false;
        }
    }
    if(!enc){
        resultado[contador] = datosB[i];
        contador++;
    }
}

delete[] datosA;
delete[] datosB;



ofstream fout("resultado.txt");
if(fout){
    for(int i = 0; i < tamResultado; i++){
        fout<< resultado[i];
    }
    fout.close();
}

delete[] resultado;

datosA = datosB = resultado = 0;

return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Could you please post sample input and output as well?

Comment: Can you please mark out the line in the code where it happens, like with a comment? Also, at that line, what are the values of the involved variables? And what do the input files look like? What are the values of `tamA` and `tamB`?

Comment: Why don't you use vectors of strings rather than those string arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your conditions.

You are changing your flag whenever you come across different element. But it should happen only when ALL of the elements in the array A are different from the one in the array B for specific position.

The way it is written now, you are trying to add all four elements from array B to your resulting array which is segmentation fault because you are trying to access unallocated memory.

One possible solution would be to add counter which checks if both elements in array A are different from the element in array B.

Something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tamB; i++){
    bool enc = true;
    // counter that keeps track of number of different elements
    int count = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < tamA && enc; j++){
        if(datosB[i] != datosA[j]){
            count++;
        }
    }
    // check if all elements in datosA are different than datosB[i]
    if(count == tamA){  
        resultado[contador] = datosB[i];
        contador++;
    } }
```

That should work as intended.